# facebook login on Android phones without facebook app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am sharing on facebook from my application.

Everything was working just fine at first (with the debug Hash Key) , until I put the 'release Hash Key' in the app settings on facebook developers. Now the problem that occurs is that users who don't have the Facebook app are redirected to 'sign in' from the fb-sdk WebView, but it's not giving the user a chance to sign in -> it shows the 'You are not signed in View'

Comment: can you post some log or picture of your problem

Comment: I think you might be having the save problem as me (unresolved):http://stackoverflow.com/q/29999310/2620328