# Which Facebook SDK should I use?

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have downloaded the latest version of the Facebook SDK. Im currently following this guide on how to implement facebook login to my app:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android

But this guide seems to be out of date, because they have removed Session. Instead, they have Introduced AccessToken, LoginManager and CallbackManager classes.

I can't find any guides where they show how to implement facebook login with the new SDK.

Is It OK to use an older version that uses the Session class Instead?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29999310/android-facebook-sdk-4-0-login-without-facebook-app

Comment: @MicheleLacorte: And?

Comment: and what? there is everything you need

Comment: Is It Ok to use a older version of the SDK?

Comment: It is incorrect and not advisable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31327897/custom-facebook-login-button-android/31332928#31332928    check the facebook login code. here step by step solution is given. It's done with new facebook sdk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add this to your Gradle file in android studio too add Facebook SDK to your project.

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.5.0'
```

[Latest Facebook SDK == 4.5.0 at this time](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use the latest SDK. And the docs you referenced to should have updated tutorials: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.4

Moreover, our SDK is bundled with various sample projects that help you understand the Login process among other features, e.g.: [HelloFacebookSample](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/HelloFacebookSample/src/com/example/hellofacebook/HelloFacebookSampleActivity.java#L121-L155)